# How to split a string into characters in python?

Tags: python, string, list, character

I know that:

```
print(list('Hello'))
```

will print

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

and I know that

```
print(list('Hello world!'))
```

will print

```
['Hello', 'world!']
```

What syntax would be easiest to get:

```
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

Answer (score 16):

`list('Hello world!')` gives what you want, not `['Hello', 'world!']`.

```
>>> print(list('Hello world!'))
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```

I think you confused the output of [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> print('Hello world!'.split())
['Hello', 'world!']
```

Answer (score 2):

work under python 3.6

```
 a = "Hello world!"
 listresp = list(map(list, a))
 listff =[]
 print (listresp)
 for charersp in listresp:
     for charfinnal in charersp:
         listff.append(charfinnal)
 print (listff)


 ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!']
```